# Why when a certain boolean variable is true, the Unity editor crashes?

Tags: unity, debugging

In my game I've got a timer script, which counts down unless the game is paused, but whenever the variable for pausing is true, something in the timer script makes the editor itself crash, and I have to pull out the task manager to close unity because it freezes up completely.

Timer.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour {

  public LevelManager levelManager;

  // Use this for initialization
  void Start () {
    levelManager = FindObjectOfType<LevelManager>();
    StartCoroutine ("timerUpdate");
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update () {
  }

  IEnumerator timerUpdate (){
    while (levelManager.levelTimeSeconds>0) {
      if (levelManager.isPause== false){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        levelManager.levelTimeSeconds -= 1;
      }
    }
    levelManager.isOver = true;
  }
}
```

Anyone have any idea what's causing the editor to crash once `isPause` is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when it becomes true your loop will run forever :) Better use:

```
while (levelManager.levelTimeSeconds>0 && levelManager.isPause== false)
{
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        levelManager.levelTimeSeconds -= 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

While loops must be used **WITH CAUTION**. A lot of times if `while` is not used in a correct manner it will always be `true`. Infinite loops can cause a program to crash, freeze or hang, like you experienced.

If dealing with arrays, use `foreach` instead if possible.

In case you're new to `foreach` syntax:

```
foreach (type elementname in variablename) { /*code here*/ }
```